# Generate EML Content ( Add file as an attachment)

Tags: c#, outlook, eml

I am trying to implement email functionality on JavaScript based front end. My task is to open default email client (mostly outlook) with an attachment (file). I used mailto, but it doesn't support attachments. Now instead of getting downloaded file as a blob from server, i am trying to get eml based blob, download it, and I assume it will open successfully in outlook with attachment. I am not very well versed in backend ( c# ), so any help will be appreciated.
I have this code which gets me the downloaded file path

```
var fileDetail = await service.DownloadFile(id);

var bytes = File.Exists(fileDetail.Path);

var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
return File(stream, fileDetail.MimeType, fileDetail.DownloadFileName);
```

FileDetail contains filePath, mimeType, fileName etc. This file can be pdf, tiff or any text file.

My aim is to generate an email file with the attached file above that i get ( no need of recipent,subject etc) . Do proper mime type for email, and send it to front end for download.

Comment: I dont know how to generate eml file with downloaded file as an attachment

Comment: Only HTML email format supports attachments.  If you are using text you cannot add an attachment.

Comment: @jdweng - absolutely not (see below). You are probably thinking about a single part message that only has a plain text body part.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko : MIME is HTML.  MIME can contain text.  Some emails are only text (Content-Type).  An email has a main Content-Type and then if MIME each MIME multipart can has its own type.

Comment: @jdweng - no, MIME is not HTML. MIME is a way for a message to contain multiple parts - plain and/or HTML body, attachments, other messages that can in turn contain plain/HTML body and its own attachments. There is absolutely no requirement that HTML body must be present if you want attachments in a message. A sample message below is an example of that.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko : Most email utilities have only two options 1) Text 2) HTML which may not exactly agree with the email specification.  You can only add attachments when you selected the HTML option.  That was my original point.

Comment: Can you name that utility? No email client application I know (Outlook / Lotus Notes / Eudora / etc.) allow attachments with HTML only.

Comment: @jdweng - I am not aware of a single email client that won't let you add an attachment to a plain text message. Outlook certainly allows that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of a plain text + attachment, make the main part `Content-Type: multipart/mixed`, convert the attachment data to base 64

```cs
byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
```

add two parts to the MIME message: one `text/plain`, another `application/octet-stream` with the base 64 encoded file data (see below).

As a test, your can create a test EML message by drafting it in Outlook and sending ti to a Gmail mailbox - you can then look at the raw MIME source of the message in your Gmail mailbox. Or you can convert any message in Outlook to MIME using [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) - open or select a message, click `IConverterSession` button on the OutlookSopy ribbon, click `MAPIToMIMEStm`.

```
From: "It's Siddiqi" <your.email@domain.demo>
To: <test@domain.demo>
Subject: test
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
    boundary="----=_NextPart_000_001A_01DA7B03.A146C8E0"
Content-Language: en-us

This is a multipart message in MIME format.

------=_NextPart_000_001A_01DA7B03.A146C8E0
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Test body

------=_NextPart_000_001A_01DA7B03.A146C8E0
Content-Type: application/octet-stream;
    name="test.bin"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
    filename="test.bin"

5XAGkAbgBkAG...
...<youyr base 64 data>
AAoADQAKAA==

------=_NextPart_000_001A_01DA7B03.A146C8E0--
```

Comment: Thank you, It works as expected when opening eml files in outlook, with proper attachments . One more thing, when opening with Mail App (default windows mail), it doesn't work not as expected.

Comment: The old Windows Mail App is no longer supported. Did you mean the new web based Outlook mail client?

Comment: Default windows mail app present in window by default.

Comment: And what exactly happens when it is used to open the message?